# creating a loop to save images from contour slice

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the following code to plot a slice at any location in a fluid volume.

```
clc, clear all, close all
format long
%a ddpath('\\ds.leeds.ac.uk\staff\staff6\censsar\Polydisperse'); % <------Change

%% Import data
input = importdata('lci_000210.dat',' ',3);
nx = 96;
ny = 96;
nz = 49;

x = input.data(:,1);
y = input.data(:,2);
z = input.data(:,3);
Lci = input.data(:,4);

L3d = reshape(Lci,[nx,ny,nz]); 
x3d = reshape(x,[nx,ny,nz]); 
y3d = reshape(y,[nx,ny,nz]); 
z3d = reshape(z,[nx,ny,nz]); 

contourslice(y3d,x3d,z3d,L3d,[],[],[0.3]);
ax=gca;
ax.Children(1).LineStyle='none';
ax.Children(2).LineStyle='none';
ax.Children(3).LineStyle='none';
view(25,20);
colormap jet
colorbar
```

What I would like to do is have the contour slice in a loop so that it creates and saves a slice at each z location. I want to hopefully create a movie of the z slice moving from zero and going up the 3d axis.

I have tried something like:

```
Z=[0 0.1 0.5];
for S = 1:length(Z)
    h = figure
    contourslice(y3d,x3d,z3d,L3d,[],[],[Z],10); 
    saveas(h,sprintf('Fig%d.png',S));
end
```

but this is not working, I am not sure how to define the z axis in the loop, so it creates a slice at each point.

Here is the [link to my data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oqedi55q0qz7qv6/lci_000210.dat?dl=0), it is a .dat file so it contains the data in 4 columns.

Comment: FYI, It is good practice to add all relevant information to your original question by editing it, instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a set of slices in a loop you have to modify your code by replacing the last but one parameter in the call to `contourslice` by specifiybg the `i-th` element of the array `Z`.

Since you did not post your input data I've tested the proposed solution on an example data from [MatLab contourslice help](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourslice) slightly modified in which

> are created nine contour plots in the y-z plane, no plots in the x-z plane, and one plot in the x-y plane by specifying Sx as a vector of nine elements, Sy as an empty vector, and Sz as a scalar (from MatLab help).

Yoy have to adapt the definition of the `Sx`, `Sy` and `Sz` parameters to your needs.

To create a movie you can use the functions:

- [videowriter](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html) to create the video object
- `open` to open the video file
- [getframe](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) to capture axes or figure as movie frame
- `close` to close and save the video file

As an alternative to the movie, you can create an `animated gif` by using the function [imwrite](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html)

```
% Load input data
[X,Y,Z,V] = flow;
% Define the parameters for the set of slices
Sx = 1:9;
Sy = [];
Sz = [];
cvals = linspace(-8,2,10);
% Open the FIGURE window
figure
% Create the axes and set tehiur properties
axis([0,10,-3,3,-3,3])
hold on
daspect([1,1,1])
campos([0,-20,7])
box on
% Create the movie object
mov=VideoWriter('contour_slice_movie.avi');
% Open the movie file
open(mov);
% Define the number of frames to be captured for each slice
n_frame_x_image=33;
% Loop over the desired number of slices
for i=1:length(Sx)
   contourslice(X,Y,Z,V,Sx(i),Sy,Sz,cvals)
   % Capture the frames
   for j=1:n_frame_x_image
      FF=getframe(gcf);
      writeVideo(mov,FF);
   end
end
% Close the movie file
close(mov);
```

[image]

Comment: This is  a link to the data file https://www.dropbox.com/s/oqedi55q0qz7qv6/lci_000210.dat?dl=0